# Flutter | Android Unable to remove unwanted permission from plugin

Tags: android, flutter, permissions, android-manifest

I am using flutter_inappbrowser plugin and it has a RECORD_AUDIO permission in its sample app.
which is getting added in main app Manifest file.
I am trying to remove it by using

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" tools:node="remove"/>
```

but it is not working. I am still able to see it in main app manifest file when decompiled.
is there any other way to remove it from App?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the correct path name in the android:name attribute. The correct name for the RECORD_AUDIO method is

> "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO",

with no spaces.

Comment: it was a typo . corrected.. thanks for pointing out. any idea how to remove the permission from sample app?